# bootstrap thumbnails second row not sitting correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I seem to run into this problem all the time and I'd love some advice from a bootstrap guru.

the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcfearn/WgU9b/5/) demonstrates the problem, because there's a row-fluid on the parent container only the first row of the thumbnails sits correctly the rest are inset (i.e. the third thumbnail does not sit directly below the first thumbnail).

the code is as follows:

```
<div class="container row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <p>som content here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="span6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" />
                </div>
            </li>    
            <li class="span6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" />
                </div>
            </li>    
            <li class="span6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" />
                </div>
            </li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What behavior are you trying to replicate? Do you want them all on the same line? If so, your problem is that you can only have two span6 elements per row.

Comment: no the problem is that the third thumb is not sitting directly under the first thumb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out this is a known issue/bug in Bootstrap, the current work-around is to add something like this to your css - which I can confirm works well:

```
li.thumbfix.span12 + li { margin-left : 0px; }
li.thumbfix.span6:nth-child(2n + 3) { margin-left : 0px; }
li.thumbfix.span4:nth-child(3n + 4) { margin-left : 0px; }
li.thumbfix.span3:nth-child(4n + 5) { margin-left : 0px; }
li.thumbfix.span2:nth-child(6n + 7) { margin-left : 0px; }
li.thumbfix.span1:nth-child(12n + 13) { margin-left : 0px; }
```

The original fix didn't include the thumbfix, but I've added this class in so that I can specifically target broken thumbnail lists and leave any that don't suffer the problem alone.

Comment: Any solution for converting this to Bootstrap 3.x.x using the col system?

Comment: I don't believe BS3 suffers from the same problem... I've created similar thumbnail grids in BS3 and not come across this issue. Here's an example http://www.cavvanbah.com/photos

Answer (score 0):

You're having 3 span6 elements inside 1 span6 element, there's no space so the third thumbnail is wrapping, that's why you see this, you also didn't set rows to logically organise them, try this:

```
<div class="container row-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <p>some content here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <ul class="thumbnails">
                <li>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 offset6">
            <ul class="thumbnails">
                <li>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but all the thumbs need to be in the same list as they are being generated by a knockoutjs foreach

Comment: Are they always going to be 3 thumbs ? can you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: there might be 20 thumbs - in which case every row but the first one will only have 1 in it as there isn't enough room for the other 18 to display side-by-side because of the hanging margin. Try adding some more in the jsfiddle example you will see the problem

Comment: Could you add the rows inside the `ul` element? See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BPVac/

Comment: It's incorrect to do it this way, you're not supposed to put rows inside `ul`, however, if you check this page http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html and head to the fluid nesting header, it might help you a bit more !, you must put rows after each 2 items, or simply put 3 smaller items.. no other way around